creating mock galaxies with galsim
For completeness analysis on JWST NIRCam images , I want to insert mock galaxies into the image and then retrieve the inserted galaxies. I want to create galaxies with sersic profile , n=1 and in a absolute magnitude range of -16 to -24 with the half light radius following a lognormal trend . How can I achieve this with the help of galsim
